# Laravel HTTP Client Missing Body Parameter

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I've tried to switch my internal Guzzle Client to Laravel's new HTTP Client. But unfortunately I'm not receiving the same response. I've als tried to send the Parameter with the HTTP asForm request but then receiving a sever error.

Any ideas? Best regards, Stan

**Guzzle Request**

```
            $body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' . $request->code . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($redirect_url);


            $client = new Client();

            $response = $client->post($endpoint, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                ],
                'auth' => [
                    $client_id,
                    $client_secret,
                ],
                'body' => $body,
            ]);
```

**Http Request**

```
       $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ])->
        withBasicAuth($client_id, $client_secret)
        ->post($token_endpoint,
                [
                    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'code' => $request->code,
                    'redirect_uri' => urlencode($redirect_url)
                ]);
```

**Error

[image]

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 4):

Removing the custom Header type and using asForm() solves the problem.

```
$response = Http::withBasicAuth($client, $client_secret)
            ->asForm()->post($endpoint,
                [
                    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'code' => $request->code,
                    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_url
                ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client#request-data

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's HTTP client does not respect your content header.

Here's my request:

```php
Http::withHeaders([
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
])
    ->withBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
    ->withoutVerifying()
    ->post('test-app.test', [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => 'asdf',
        'redirect_uri' => 'asdf',
    ]);
```

Here's what my application received for the body:

```
"{"grant_type":"authorization_code","code":"asdf","redirect_uri":"asdf"}"
```

You're probably confusing the OAuth server by telling it that you sent `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when you actually sent `application/json`.

Try updating your code to use the correct content type:

```php
Http::withHeaders([
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
])
//
```

Comment: Hi @Sturm thanks a lot for your answer. I've tested your code and receive the same error. Is this a bug or should I open a issue on the Laravel Repo?

Comment: My code will also receive an error. Because my code specifies that I'm using `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but I'm actually sending JSON, the application that receives my request is rightly confused. Change the Content-Type header and see if that fixes your problem. @StanBarrows