# Getting an HTTP Client 400 error using Guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle, laravel-10

I am trying to make an HTTP client request in Laravel. I have tried using Guzzle directly, and it works, but when doing it through "API around the Guzzle HTTP client" in Laravel, I always get a 400. I can't find where the error is since it seems to be correct. I give the example of the two cases.

$method = 'post', and route and $headers are the same too.

**Guzzle (200 success)**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request($method, $this->BASEURL . $endpoint, [
    'body' => '{"name":"testName"}',
    'headers' => $headers,
]);
```

**Laravel HTTP Client (400 bad request)**

```
$response = Http::withHeaders($headers)
    ->withBody('{"name":"testName"}', 'application/json')
    ->{$method}($this->BASEURL . $endpoint);
```

**Example from AirbnbAPI using Guzzle**

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.airbnb.com/v2/listings', [
    'body' => '{"name":"erer"}',
    'headers' => [
        'X-Airbnb-API-Key' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        'X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token' => 'XXXXXX',
        'X-Airbnb-Req-Api-Version' => '2022.12.31',
        'accept' => 'application/json',
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: is your BASEURL is same as you app url?

Comment: No, base url is initialized in the class. In both cases it is the same

Comment: Does your `$headers` variable have the content-type defined? If it does, and the key is not `'Content-Type'` (case sensitive), this may cause your issue.

Comment: Please, do read the documentation as it is perfectly explained how to use the [`Http`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client) facade...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 7 HTTP Client - Unable to send POST request with \`body\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550730/laravel-7-http-client-unable-to-send-post-request-with-body)

Comment: Wrong link, meant to use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527282/laravel-http-client-missing-body-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in the json body directly when calling the method as a second argument:

```php
    $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->{$method}($this->BASEURL . $endpoint, ['name' => 'testName']);
```

By default data will be sent using the application/json content type.

Comment: Ok this works :). But do you know why with Guzzle I can pass it in the body and not using the Laravel withBody() method?

Comment: It is a facade, read the documentation on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

If your `$headers` array has a "content-type" key that is not cased as `Content-Type`, then the issue may be that you're sending over multiple content-type headers.

For example, if your `$headers` array has a `content-type` key, then with the call to `withHeaders()`, you're setting the `content-type` header.

The next call to `withBody()` will then set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Since the header names are keys in an array, and they are not the same (array keys are case sensitive), the headers array will end up with both a `content-type` header and a `Content-Type` header, and both will be sent in the request.

You either need to remove the `content-type` entry from your `$headers` variable, or you need to ensure it is cased as `Content-Type` so the Http client will overwrite it properly.